# SQL table linking wont work for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to link three different SQL tables together (users, details and system) and to print the results using this query:

```
SELECT 
    users.user_id, users.user_email, system.date, system.time, 
    system.table_layout, details.party_size, details.children_no, 
    details.diets, details.occassion, details.more
FROM 
    users, system, details
WHERE 
    users.user_id = system.id = details.ID
ORDER BY 
    users.user_id
```

However, it only prints the users and systems information correctly, and does not display the details column correctly - it just repeats one column it has inside.
How do I successfully link three tables together? As only two connect at the moment

Comment: I'd suggest reading through this script on relational database design: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best to use explicit joins.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_email, system.date, system.time, system.table_layout, details.party_size, details.children_no, details.diets, details.occassion, details.more
FROM users
Join system  on users.user_id = system.id
Join details on system.id = details.ID
ORDER BY users.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much you legend!

Comment: @aei Happy it helped.  Thanks for the grin.

Comment: Hi again, @john-cappelletti, I'm having a new issue. I have realised, that one user is unable to link to multiple data in details and system column without a linking column so I created 'customer_id' in both the tables to link them, I then included this in my new coding. However, the user with multiple data in the other two columns, SQL is repeating it twice as many times. How do I solve this?

Comment: Heres my coding: SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id , users.user_email , system.date , system.time , system.table_layout , details.party_size , details.children_no , details.diets , details.occassion , details.more FROM users Join system on users.user_id = system.customer_id Join details on system.customer_id = details.customer_id ORDER BY users.user_id

Comment: @aei A little hard without a visual.  The updated query looks perfectly valid.

Comment: hi, feel free to ignore me if youre busy but this is my new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131469/how-to-link-three-sql-tables-together

Comment: @aei Ah.  I see why I didn't see your new question.  I'm not a MySQL guy.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your choice of naming for ids is just confusing (it is not clear if
`system.id` and `details.ID` refer both to `users.user_id` or not), but it looks like you are not joining tables on the right keys.

In order to join (link) tables, each table needs a **private key** (id) and a **foreign key** (id of the table you want to join).

Assuming your tables have the following schema:
*Users(**id**, email, ...)

System(id, **user_id**, date, time, table_layout)

Details(id, **user_id**, party_size, diets, ...)*

You can join them with

```
SELECT *
FROM users, system, details
WHERE users.id = system.user_id AND users.id = details.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id;
```

Or do it with the inner join, like John Cappelletti suggested:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN system ON users.id = system.user_id
JOIN details ON users.id = details.user_id
WHERE users.id = system.user_id AND users.id = details.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id;
```

Comment: maybe you might be able to help me with my new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131469/how-to-link-three-sql-tables-together